# Download file in service object with ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

A user uploads a document and this gets stored in Azure with ActiveStorage. The next step is that the backend processes this and therefore I have a service object to do this. So I need to download the file from Azure to the `tmp` folder within the Rails app. How do I download the file? I cannot use `rails_blob_url` because it is not available in a service object, only in controllers and views.

When I still used Paperclip I did something like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
file = Rails.root.join('tmp', user.attachment_file_name)
name = user.attachment_file_name
download = open(user.attachment.url)
download_result = IO.copy_stream(download, file)
```

How can I do something similar with ActiveStorage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ActiveStorage::Blob#open](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-open):

> Downloads the blob to a tempfile on disk. Yields the tempfile.

Given this example from the guides:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

You can do this with:

```
user.avatar.open do |tempfile|
  # do something with the file
end
```

If its `has_many_attached` you of course need to loop through the attachments.

See:

- [Active Storage Overview](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#downloading-files)

Comment: If you really want to get the url to an attachment you can get it through the [`#url`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-url) method on the blob instead of the helper method.

Comment: This: `# do something with the file` -> how can I download the file to the 'tmp' folder in the Rails app?

Comment: Use `user.avatar.open(tmpdir: Rails.root.join('tmp')) do ...`. But as it is a tempfile it is automatically closed and unlinked at the end of the block. If you want to make the file permanent  use `ObjectSpace.undefine_finalizer(tempfile)` or use `Blob#download` instead to stream the download into a regular File/IO instance.